# JSON Data using ember.js

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

The following is an API resonpse (sample url http://api.example.com/data.json)

```
{
      "results":[
        {
          "id":"4422",
            "updated":"Mon Jun 26 15:01:05 GMT 2006",
              "description":"Meet fellow Social Networkers near you! Come to a local Social Networking Meetup to make valuable social connections and cultivate relationships with other elbow-rubbers in your area.",
             "name":"Social Networking",
             "link":"http:\/\/socialnetwork.meetup.com\/",
             "urlkey":"socialnetwork",
             "members":"245701"
          }
       ],
       "meta":{
          "id":"",
          "title":"Meetup Topics",
          "count":1,
          "updated":"",
          "description":"API for accessing meetup topics",
          "next":"",
          "link":"http:\/\/api.meetup.com\/topics\/",
          "method":"Topics",
          "total_count":3063,
          "url":"http:\/\/api.meetup.com\/topics\/\/?order=members&key=1&page=1&format=json&desc=0&offset=0",
          "prev":""
       }
    }
```

Using plain javascript, I can do

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://api.example.com/data.json', false);
req.send();
json = req.responseText;
object = JSON.parse(json)['results'];
console.log(object.id);
console.log(object.link);
```

How do I get that using ember.js and ember-data , able to access properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to use ember-data in this case, because if you want to, either need to follow [conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions) the or [create your own adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/)

But you can, still consume this data without ember-data, using plain old jQuery.

```
var request = Ember.$.getJSON('http://api.example.com/data.json');

request.then(function(object) {
 console.log(object);
});
```